# Jquery CSS and JS to limited elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, salesforce

I want to apply my Jquery mobile CSS and JS to only some limited elements and to no other elements on the page. any idea how I can do that.

I have some Salesforce standard Customer Portal in which I am including a tab which is having Jquery ,mobile and CSS.

Now when I open the tab in Customer Portal , then  it overrides Salesforce standard styling.

Thanks

Comment: what element?? what page?? what CSS?? What JS??

Comment: jQM version, more details..

Comment: just $(selector).action() will work for that.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on jQuery Mobile version you're using.

1. **Solution 1:**

   - Modify *Global Settings* on `mobileinit`, by setting `ignoreContentEnabled` to *true*. However, this affects app performance negatively, as it slows down processing/initializing widgets/elements.

     ```
     <head>
       <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
       <script>
         $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
           $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
         });
       </script>
       <script src="jQuery-Mobile.js"></script>
     <head>
     ```
   - Add `data-enhance="false"` to elements or div you want to keep untouched by jQM.

     ```
     <div data-role="content" data-enhance="false">
       <!-- elements -->
     </div>

     <input type="text" data-enhance="false">
     ```

---

2. **Solution 2:**

   - Modify *page* widget defaults on `mobileinit`, by setting a *.selector* for `keepNative`. The *.selector* could be a `<tag>`, an `#id` or a `.class`.

     - jQuery Mobile <= 1.3.x

       ```
       <head>
         <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
         <script>
           $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
             $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative + ", input, #foo, .native";
           });
         </script>
         <script src="jQuery-Mobile.js"></script>
       <head>
       ```
     - jQuery Mobile >= 1.4.x

       ```
       <head>
         <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
         <script>
           $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
             $.mobile.keepNative = $.mobile.keepNative + ", input, #foo, .native";
           });
         </script>
         <script src="jQuery-Mobile.js"></script>
       <head>
       ```

     When page is being created, `input`, element with `#foo` ID and elements with `native` class, will be kept as is.

---

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DTtAW/)**

Comment: here in the example you have mentioned that I can specify where to use native styling. can it be done other way round like where to apply the Jquery styling.? Thanks

Comment: @KaushikRay it cant be done this way, because by default elements are enhanced unless otherwise you tell jQM not to. You can use first solution for complete div, solution two for specific elements, you combine both solutions too.