# Add Jquery mobile to one Div while not to other in same HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scope

I need only some elements in my page to have jquery styling

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>
<div id="noJquery">
 //components should not have jquery mobile styling CSS
</div> 
<div data-role="page">
  //Only Jquery contents here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea how I can achieve this.. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery CSS and JS to limited elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184234/jquery-css-and-js-to-limited-elements)

Comment: you just asked the same question.