# jquery mobile styling my page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Something strange is happening.

I currently use jquery UI, but am looking to use jquery mobile.

I added mobile to my website header and did nothing else but jqm decides all by itself to style my buttons, inputs etc. What's that all about?

Call me old fashioned but surely its the develop that tells the code how to act not the other way around.

Is there a way of stopping jqm acting this way?

Comment: Could you give an example of this styling and some of the code?  I used jqm, and the automatic styling it did was exactly what I wanted.  Since there was an established mobile look and feel, it made sense.  I had no desire to swim against the (mobile) current in terms of style, so I was happy it took that burden off of me.

Comment: Yes but it restyling my website whether it is a mobile or desktop browser.

Comment: Right, but if it's a mobile library, it may assume you're accessing it from mobile...  When I used jqm (IIRC), I did it for a mobile sub-domain, the idea being that anyone who went there wanted a mobile experience, regardless of browser.

Comment: Well, this is the way jQM works. By default it enhances all elements with its' styles. You can control this behavior if you want.

Comment: @Omar - Hows that work?

Comment: In many ways. What do you exactly want? Keep input, buttons,...etc untouched? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21185237/1771795