# How to prevent jqm completely from styling my element (data-role=none is not doing the job)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I know the standard answer for this question is

```
 data-role="none"
```

or

```
data-enhance="false"
```

And yes they work, but only partially. There are still some styles left on the Element, is there any possibility to completely ignore a style sheet for some elements?
I think these styles which are left on my element are just inherited from body etc. Can i prevent that?

Comment: A closed duplicate with no answer and an unclear question... That helps a lot

Comment: the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21185237/1771795