# Why is jQuery conflicting with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

The libraries that are included in my HTML page are

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">       
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Modernizer Script for old Browsers -->
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<!-- Single Page Nav -->
<script src="js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery.fancybox.pack -->
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery easing -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fullscreen slider -->
<script src="js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
<!-- onscroll animation -->
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Functions -->
<script src="mzaes.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

In my web page before including

```
js/jquery.mobile.1.4.5.min.js
and
css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css
```

the bootstrap modal window was like this modal window 
[image]

and slider(input range) was like this
[image]

But after adding those two libraries it became like this 
[image]
and
[image]

Why that's happening? Whats the problem?

Comment: Are there any Console errors in Inspector / Firebug, etc?

Comment: not jquery <-> jquerymobile is the problem. the both css files from jquerymobile and bootstrap are the problem. Both are styling the radio buttons.

Comment: @Ridrog please tell me what to do now...

Comment: hard to say. mixin jquerymobile and bootstrap is no good idea. you have to decide what you need more: jqm or bootstrap. Or maybe try to include the jquerymobile css before bootstrap. If you really need both you have to include your own rules or delete the rules in jqm or bootstrap that you dont need

Comment: add `data-role="none"` to any element you don't want to be styled by jQM or use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21185237/1771795

Comment: Thanks man Its Working perfect... ;) @Omar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `data-role="none"` to any element you don't want to be styled by jQueryMobile

You can also refer this question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21185237/1771795